# Can we reopen Word for the best way to move from point A to point B?

Tags: discussion

I cast the fifth VTC on [Word for the best way to move from point A to B?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373914/word-for-the-best-way-to-move-from-point-a-to-b) without reading all the comments.  To my dismay, the OP had provided context in a comment I overlooked.  (Oh, the guilt!)  I edited the question, and voted to reopen.  It is a deserving question, and needs only two more votes to open.

Comment: It is now open once more.

Comment: You did exactly the right thing by closing a question which should have been closed. No guilt needed. And exactly the right thing in editing the information in which the asker should have done; and exactly the right thing in asking here about re-opening it.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Thanks!